# Travis CI, update CMake using the packages cache

Tags: cmake, package, travis-ci

I'm using this snippet to pre-install a desired compiler version inside a travis Virtual Machine

```
 - os: linux
  compiler: clang
  addons:
    apt:
      sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test', 'llvm-toolchain-precise-3.5']
      packages: ['clang-3.5']
  env: COMPILER=clang++-3.5
```

This has the advantage of running the build inside a machine without using `sudo` which results in a faster build.

How do I use that to install cmake 2.8.12 (or more recent) both on linux and osx when using travis? I tried

```
  - os: linux
  compiler: clang
  addons:
    apt:
      sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test', 'llvm-toolchain-precise-3.5', 'add-apt-repository']
      packages: ['clang-3.5', 'ppa:kalakris/cmake']
  env: COMPILER=clang++-3.5
```

without success

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... How did you know to use Clang 3.5? What if you needed Clang 4.0 or 5.0? (I'm using Travis and Clang 3.8 is default. Clang is broken so I need to upgrade it. I don't know what I should upgrade to).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To install cmake from kalakris, use:

```
addons:
    apt:
      packages:
        - cmake
      sources:
        - kalakris-cmake
```

For a more recent CMake (from https://github.com/ldionne/hana/blob/master/.travis.yml)

```
if [[ "${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}" == "linux" ]]; then
  CMAKE_URL="http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.3/cmake-3.3.1-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz"
  mkdir cmake && travis_retry wget --quiet -O - ${CMAKE_URL} | tar --strip-components=1 -xz -C cmake
  export PATH=${DEPS_DIR}/cmake/bin:${PATH}
else
  brew install cmake
fi
```

A full snippet in your case is:

```
 - os: linux
  compiler: clang
  addons:
    apt:
      sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test', 'llvm-toolchain-precise-3.7', 'kalakris-cmake']
      packages: ['clang-3.7', 'cmake']
  env: COMPILER=clang++-3.7
```

Comment: I seem to fail the syntax for using both cmake and particular GCC, how can I integrate `- cmake`, `- kalakris-cmake` with the scripts in my example above? thanks

Comment: you can either write a oneliner list with [ ] or a multiline list with dashes. So you can write `sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test', 'llvm-toolchain-precise-3.5', 'kalakris-cmake']` and `packages: ['clang-3.5', 'cmake']`

Answer (score 0):

A very bad hack ( travis cmake is not at /usr/bin )

```
before_install:
- wget -q -O - https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc | sudo apt-key add -
- sudo apt-add-repository -y 'deb https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ bionic main'
- sudo apt-get update -y -qq

install:
- sudo apt-get install -y cmake

script:
- /usr/bin/cmake ..
- make
```